# JSON: Parse a name (not value) of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

I have a json array parsed from an api as such:

[image]

An I want to parse the **pageid**.

I could do `console.log(parsed_json["query"]["pages"]["42743"]["pageid"])` but everytime that **"42743" under pages** changes.

How could I parse the name under pages so I could use:

```
console.log(parsed_json["query"]["pages"][" >> ID << "]["pageid"])
```

Comment: That's not "parsing", that's "accessing" - you have the parsed object already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `pages` object will only ever have that one, enumerable key, you could do;

```
var pages = parsed_json.query.pages;
var page;

for (var x in pages) {
    if (pages.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
        page = x;
    }
}

// use pages[page].pageid;
```

... this enumerates the properties, and records the last one that was enumerated. `break` on the first or whatever if you need. For laughs, this could be cleaner in ES5:

```
var pages = parsed_json.query.pages;
var page = Object.keys(pages)[0];

// use pages[page].pageid;
```